# codeigniter get image_height and image_width after image_lib manipulation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm uploading a file to the server using 
`$this->upload->data()`

I'm using the code from here https://gist.github.com/codee/3927343 
To fix the rotation according to EXIF.
(eventually using `$CI->image_lib->rotate();`)
The question is: How to I "refresh" the `image_width` and `image_height` to be correct after the rotation?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone reaches here - the answer for reference:

Calling:
`$this->upload->set_image_properties($full_path);`

and then re-calling - `$this->upload->data()` did the trick